# Complex Laravel collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I'm having some issues with the Laravel Collection class.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I have a multisite solution in which a site has "facilitators". Sometimes one facilitator appears on multiple sites, and not just one.
- I want to list all the facilitators and the website they're on the main page, but I don't want multiple users.

**So what I currently do is:**

- Get the Facilitators.
- Use Collection to collect the facilitators and use `unique('name')`.

This gives me unique facilitators, but only picks the first one it detects and then deletes the other ones.

**So lets say I have this collection:**

```
Collection { 
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => "John"
      "site" => "Example"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "name" => "Martin"
      "site" => "Another"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      "name" => "John"
      "site" => "Another"
    ]
  ]
}
```

With `unique()` I would get:

```
Collection { 
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => "John"
      "site" => "Example"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "name" => "Martin"
      "site" => "Another"
    ]
  ]
}
```

*And this is what I want to get:*

```
Collection { 
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => "John"
      "site" => ["Example", "Another"]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "name" => "Martin"
      "site" => "Another"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this with Laravel's collection class?

Comment: Why don't you use `Group_concat` ? This may solve your issue.

Comment: The site is not assigned to the user on a DB level. I'm looping over all of the sites, find their facilitators and then add the site name to the facilitator object. I would really have to do this with the collection. Basically what I'm trying to do is: get the unique but merge one key.

Comment: Try to use `GroupBy`. Here is the example. This may help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When stuck with collections always remember [reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-reduce) is a powerful tool in your arsenal.

Building on Sam's answer which I couldn't get to work, I think using reduce alongside groupBy should work...

```
$sites = collect([
  ["name" => "John", "site" => "Example"],
  ["name" => "Martin", "site" => "Another"],
  ["name" => "John", "site" => "Another"],
]);

$sites->groupBy('name')->reduce(function ($result, $item) {
  $result[] = [
    'name' => $item->first()['name'], 
    'sites' => $item->pluck('site')->toArray()
  ];

  return $result;
}, collect([]))->toArray();
```

And from the console...

```
λ php artisan tinker                                                                             
Psy Shell v0.8.2 (PHP 7.0.10 ÔÇö cli) by Justin Hileman                                          
>>> $sites = collect([                                                                           
...   ["name" => "John", "site" => "Example"],                                                   
...   ["name" => "Martin", "site" => "Another"],                                                 
...   ["name" => "John", "site" => "Another"],                                                   
... ]);                                                                                          
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#698                                                           
     all: [                                                                                      
       [                                                                                         
         "name" => "John",                                                                       
         "site" => "Example",                                                                    
       ],                                                                                        
       [                                                                                         
         "name" => "Martin",                                                                     
         "site" => "Another",                                                                    
       ],                                                                                        
       [                                                                                         
         "name" => "John",                                                                       
         "site" => "Another",                                                                    
       ],                                                                                        
     ],                                                                                          
   }                                                                                             
>>> $sites->groupBy('name')->reduce(function ($result, $item) {                                  
...   $result[] = ['name' => $item->first()['name'], 'sites' => $item->pluck('site')->toArray()];
...                                                                                              
...   return $result;                                                                            
... }, collect([]))->toArray();                                                                  
=> [                                                                                             
     [                                                                                           
       "name" => "John",                                                                         
       "sites" => [                                                                              
         "Example",                                                                              
         "Another",                                                                              
       ],                                                                                        
     ],                                                                                          
     [                                                                                           
       "name" => "Martin",                                                                       
       "sites" => [                                                                              
         "Another",                                                                              
       ],                                                                                        
     ],                                                                                          
   ]
```

One thing to note is that you specified in your question that the sites should return a single string if there's only one site and an array if there's many.The above solution does not provide this! I think this is inconsistent and you should always return an array for the sites key, even if it only has one value as it will make it more difficult to read and manipulate later on.

However, if this is something important, you could instead check if there are many sites when using pluck to set an array and if not you could set it as a single string, like this:

```
$sites->groupBy('name')->reduce(function ($result, $item) {
  $result[] = [
    'name' => $item->first()['name'],
    'sites' => $item->pluck('site')->count() > 1 ? $item->pluck('site') : $item->first()['site']
  ];

  return $result;
}, collect([]))->toArray();
```

which would produce...

```
[                        
  [                      
    "name" => "John",    
    "sites" => [         
      "Example",         
      "Another",         
    ],                   
  ],                     
  [                      
    "name" => "Martin",  
    "sites" => "Another",
  ],                     
]
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll dig more into the reduce method, seems like a very powerful method. Thanks

Comment: Great! Yep, you can practically reimplement any collection method with reduce. I'd highly recommend this resource if you want to dive deeper into working with collections: https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/ - happy coding!

Comment: @haakym great answer. Your answer is really Appreciable.Keep it up. God bless u.

Comment: Thanks Manish! God bless you too. Credit to Sam who posted the first answer as I began working from his answer, as my initial approach to the solution was to only use reduce which was getting a bit complex.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by chaining to get exactly what you want, assuming $collection is the main collection

```
 $collection->groupBy('name')->map(function($facilitators) {
     return ['name' => $facilitators->first()['name'], 'site' => $facilitators->pluck('site')->toArray()];
})->values()->toArray();
```

first we group by name so it will give 2 dimensional array inside collection, then iterate to that and name will be common so get it from first element, then from all the element pluck site and convert it to array, using flatMap will make it single level nested.

Comment: Have you ran this code? It didn't work for me. `$facilitators->first()->name` will return an error that it can't access name as I think the `first()` method returns an array and you're trying to access it like an object.

Comment: none of the method on collection returns array except toArray() and all() first returns the first item in collection and that item is object i think and it the item itself is array then it requires a bit modification but the dump shown in question seems it has nested collection